# TYPO3 link always resolve to default language

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I recently upgraded from TYPO3 ver. `8.x` to ver. `9.x` and I am currently running `9.5.20`.

We have a setup with 3 languages: DE (default), FR, IT

since the update, no matter what language you are currently on, every typolink leads to the default language.

the typolinks are stored in the database like this:
`<a href="t3://page?uid=686">...`

some random tidbits that might help narrow the problem down

- the 404 page works correctly and is always shown in the right language
- the only links that work correctly are the ones used by the blog extension

here are some configurations that might help solve the issue

the config.yaml file

```
additionalGetParams: ''
base: /
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://www.example.com/'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Production"'
  -
    base: 'https://www.example.com/'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
connectTimeout: 0
debugErrorPageRequestException: false
disableCertificateVerification: false
disableStatisticsRecording: false
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=141'
forceLanguage: -1
languages:
  -
    title: German
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: at
    languageId: '0'
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_CH.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: '1,0,2,3'
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: '1'
  -
    title: French
    enabled: true
    base: /fr/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_CH.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: French
    hreflang: fr-CH
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: fr
    languageId: '2'
  -
    title: Italian
    enabled: true
    base: /it/
    typo3Language: it
    locale: it_CH.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: it
    navigationTitle: Italiano
    hreflang: it-CH
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: it
    languageId: '3'
passAuthinfoToInsecureConnections: false
passthroughContentTypeHeader: false
requestTimeout: 0
rootPageId: 21
routes: {  }
trustInsecureIncomingConnections: false
```

setup.typoscript

```
    config {
        // Language Settings
        sys_language_overlay = 0
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback
        language = de
        locale_all = de_CH.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="de-CH" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
        sys_language_uid = 0
        language = de
        defaultGetVars {
            L = 0
        }
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 1
        language = en
        locale_all = en_GB.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="en" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }

[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 2
        language = fr
        locale_all = fr_FR.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="fr-CH" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }

[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 3
        language = it
        locale_all = it_IT.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="it-ch" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }

    
[global]
```

any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would remove all options not provided by the core (`forceLanguage`, `requestTimeout`, etc.) from the yaml file. The TypoScript can be removed completely as it is done via the site management.

Answer (score 0):

I think TypoScript conditions like

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
```

are not working anymore as of TYPO3 9.

Could you try the new syntax like

```
[siteLanguage("languageId") == "1"]
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInConditions.html#sitehandling-inconditions